# Looping over Pandas DataFrame and Plotting Each Column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to create a function or for loop that will display a sorted horizontal bar chart for each column of a DataFrame. An example of the code for one column can be seen below. The plt.savefig() is a nice to have but not necessary.

frame['Population-current year'] is one of the columns from the DataFrame. I can't seem to formulate the necessary structure for the loop, syntax-wise.

DataFrame header:

Place name          Population-current year
Santa Fe                            82980.0
Nashville-Davidson                 654187.0
Sandia Park                            72.0
Stone Mountain                       6209.0
Asheville                           89318.0

Place name          Pct change in population, 2010-current year  \
Santa Fe                                                 0.2277
Nashville-Davidson                                       0.1130
Sandia Park                                              0.0286
Stone Mountain                                           0.0362
Asheville                                                0.0896

Place name          Median age of population  Median age of housing  \
Santa Fe                                42.8                   34.0
Nashville-Davidson                      34.1                   38.0
Sandia Park                             60.2                   24.0
Stone Mountain                          38.8                   38.0
Asheville                               38.6                   44.0

Thanks in Advance.

```
ax = (frame['Population-current year']/1000).sort_values().plot(kind='barh', figsize=(8, 10), color='#86bf91', zorder=2, width=0.85)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")

vals = ax.get_xticks()
for tick in vals:
    ax.axvline(x=tick, linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, color='#eeeeee', zorder=1)
ax.set_title("Population - 2017 (1000s)", weight='bold', size=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Population - 2017 (1000s)", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)
ax.set_ylabel("City", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,g}'))

plt.savefig('pop_chart.png')
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? For me it just sounds like you need to loop trough the columns with something like 'for col in frame.columns'. 
Do you want to arrange the plots on a subplots or facet grid?

Comment: Yes, please supply the sample data in a format that you can easily copy-paste. What is your expected output? A separate bar graph for every column or an array of subplots?